# Why do we see the sets in this order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, education, integers, rational-numbers

There is the following question:

Why do we see in maths first the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and then the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ but in school we see first the rationals and the negative numbers?

Do you have an idea why it is like that?

Comment: Actually in the history of maths, fractions appeared before negative numbers.

Comment: Because the country your school is in decided to do it that way. AFAIR I learned the negative numbers first.

Comment: "Fractions" are quite natural: take a cake and cut slices from it...

Comment: Is this a better fit for the [matheducators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I am not sure about your statement about schools. For instance, $(-2) + 3 = 1$ can be explained to children while taking an elevator or looking at a (Celcius) thermometer.

Comment: @crostul I would love to read about the history of numbers, and of mathematics in general, do you know some book or a link that can help?

Comment: Elementary school teaches intuitively and hueristicly.  Negative numbers are subtle and not intuitive even if you imagine a hotel building with floors underground or going into debt and counting down to new years it takes a bit of insight to actually integrate them into your knowledge rather than to think of them as special cases of manipulation of the positives. You can can have fewer than zero and you can't have antimatter pocket space is a *really* strong inuition to get over..   But... To be continued....

Comment: ... continued.... when we "grow up" and sit down at a real math class and start with: "Starting with a clean slate; what is anything and how do we build up" we are not (supposed to be) impeded by intuition or biases.  Natural to Integers to Rational to Real to Complex is logistic hierarchy.  But we aren't teaching children to be mathematicians; we're teaching them to be people.  (which maybe we should teach them to be mathematicians... in the U.S. "new math" was a huge failure but... I liked it.)

Comment: @fleablood: I never considered negative numbers unintuitive. Yes, you cannot have a negative amount of things (well, actually you can, in the form of debt, but that's already a more abstract concept). But I can have two apples *less* or two apples *more,* and I doubt there is anyone who doesn't understand that concept. Or the fact that if I take away two of your apples ($-2$) and then give you three apples ($+3$), in the end you've got one apple more ($+1$).

Comment: @celtschk I think most  children will want to know what -2 apples *are*. You can say "taking away 2" but that is an *action* not an actual thing.  What does it look like if you are walking down the street with $-2$ apples and there is no one else on the street and no other apples at all?  Well, when I was a child I could see this simply as I'm holding to hungry monsters in my hands each ready to devour an apple and pop out of existence if they come across one. As distance/time is more intuitive but I think most people just treat them as positive numbers "in the other direction"

Comment: @fleablood: “I think most children will want to know what $-2$ apples *are.*” I don't think so, at least if you don't (mis-)lead them into that direction. Numbers without sign describe a number of objects, numbers with sign describe a change of objects.  I don't see how this is more complicated than that nouns describe objects and verbs describe actions. Do children ask what type of object a walk is? Note that this way, initially $+2$ and $2$ are different types of numbers; the fact that they can be treated as the same is an extra step.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should really be on the MathEducators Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why, in mathematics, the set of integers is seen first is : the rationals are defined in terms of equivalence relation on the set of integers.

So, the reason is contained in the construction process of number sets.

See : Peterson, Theory Of Arithmetics ( at archive.org).

Now, why do not school mathematics follow this order?

There was a time during which,  it was thought that school mathematics had to undergo a huge reform, in order to follow the scientific order of Modern Mathematics.

So, pupils were taught at 11 or 12 years old : sets, equivalence relations, orderings, etc.

But this led to a failure. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math)

The experience of " New mathematics" (or " Modern mathematics"), showed that the order in which mathematics are learned, is not the same as the order in which  mathematical theories actually develop.

The process of learning, is not the same as the process by which mathematical objects are constructed.

An analogy: scientifically speaking, newtonian mechanics comes after einsteinian mechanics, since the newtonian one, is a particular case relatively speaking, to the general theory of Einstein. However, at school, newtonian mechanics is seen first.

Comment: Well, the mathematics reason you give essentially is: Mathematics does it this way because mathematics does it this way. Indeed, if we define natural numbers to be without $0$, then from a purely mathematical point of view, first defining fractions (i.e. $\mathbb Q^+$) as equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers, and then defining $\mathbb Q$ as equivalence classes of fractions is even simpler, as you don't have to treat $0$ as a special case anywhere.

Comment: The way I understood the question is : why is the school mathematics order different from the standard scientific mathematical order?

Comment: But you give a reason for the mathematical order which isn't actually a reason. Indeed, I'm not sure if there actually *is* a reason other than tradition and the fact that in the end, it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: If I am correct, mathematicians admit various ways of constructing sets of numbers. But some are more " standard" than others, maybe because they are more convenient. That could be , I suppose, the object of a question on MSE. Personnaly, I'm not competent enough to explain why a given way of constructing number sets has become "standard".

Comment: My objection is that you write “The reason is” followed by something that isn't actually a reason.